# Can't prove the inequality

Tags: real-analysis

I am currently following a course on distribution theory, and there is a structure proof in the chapter of sobolev spaces, that uses the following equality to prove equivalence of 2 norms, which is essential to the proof of the structure theorem. The inequality in question is:\

Let $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ be a positive integer. Then we have the following inequality

$$
\sum\limits_{\vert \alpha\vert \leq m} \vert \xi^\alpha\vert^2 \leq (1+\vert\xi\vert^2)^m
$$

Here is what i have tried:

$$
\sum\limits_{\vert \alpha\vert \leq m} \vert \xi^\alpha\vert^2 = \sum\limits_{k=0}^m \sum\limits_{\vert \alpha\vert = k} \vert \xi^\alpha\vert^2
\leq \sum\limits_{k=0}^m \sum\limits_{\vert \alpha\vert = k} \vert \xi\vert^{2k} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^m\vert \xi\vert^{2k} \sum\limits_{\vert \alpha\vert = k} 1$$

So if $\sum\limits_{\vert \alpha\vert = k} 1$ is bounded by $\binom{m}{k}$i would be done, but this doesn't apear to be true, since $n$ could be alot smaller or alot bigger than $m$. Any help or tips would be appreciated!